# Way to have a class level type descriptor with __set__

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, descriptor

I've got data descriptors working for objects with both `__set__` and `__get__`.

It seems however, that class descriptors do not support `__set__`. Doing so instead replaces the descriptor object itself with the value assigned.

The following code demonstrates this

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print('__get__')
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print('__set__')

class Class(object):
    descriptor = Descriptor()

print('Object')
a = Class()
a.descriptor
a.descriptor = 1

print('Class')
Class.descriptor
Class.descriptor = 2
```

Which outputs

```
Object
__get__
__set__
Class
__get__
```

As you can see, the class level `__set__` did not get called.

Is there some workaround or hack (no matter how horrible) that will permit a `__set__` data descriptor on a class?

Just to be clear, I don't want calling code to have to implement any 'hack'. I want the calling code to work as expected above, but any hack to be 'behind the scenes'.

Using Python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't get into the whole Descriptor protocol. I don't *fully understand it myself*; in fact, you've reminded me that I need to quit being lazy and *really* dive into it. For the mean time, I'll say this:

What I *do* understand is that descriptors will only work their magic on instances. Now, you probably already knew this, which is why you're wondering if there's a hack to go around this limitation.

If you have the slightest familiarity with metaclasses, you'll know that classes *are instances too*. Classes can be instances of a class, which can also be an instance and so forth. This is great because what you're asking would look something like this:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print('__get__')
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print('__set__')

class MetaClass(type):
    descriptor = Descriptor()

class Class(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass

# This will work fine when you do Class.descriptor, as you asked
# but it will raise an AttributeError if you do 
# a = Class()
# a.descriptor
# Read on for the full explanation...
```

The `descriptor` variable defined in `MetaClass` is only visible to the `Class` class. Any instances of `Class` that try to call it will give you an `AttributeError`. This is because instances of classes, when searching for an attribute, search their own `__dict__` before searching the class's `__dict__`, but it won't search as far as the class's `__metaclass__`. Now, if you want to have it both ways and use the same variable name for both the class and its instances (although I wouldn't recommend it as it would invite confusion), you could do this:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print('__get__')
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print('__set__')

class MetaClass(type):
    descriptor = Descriptor()

class Class(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
    descriptor = Descriptor()
```

At this point you may be wondering: *if an instance searches its own `__dict__` before searching its class, how is it that calling '`Class.descriptor`' won't pick the same descriptor that '`a.descriptor`' uses (which, as you've observed, wouldn't work properly) if `Class.descriptor` is essentially its own instance variable (from a metaclass POV)* ?

The answer is that data descriptors (descriptors which have both `__get__` and `__set__` defined), as opposed to non-data descriptors (which have only defined `__get__`), have priority over instance variables. In other words, the `descriptor` variable in `MetaClass` is the one `Class` will pick up because it has priority over `Class`'s own `descriptor` variable. The same goes for the `Class` instance, which automatically picks up the `descriptor` variable defined in `Class`.

I hope I haven't confused you. This stuff is easy to forget, I think doubly so because it's not very common nor necessary to understand this level of magic most of the time. I had to refresh my memory on this one! Good question :)

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed =)

Comment: To clarify: when resolving `a.descriptor`, the language doesn't do the equivalent of `getattr(type(a), 'descriptor')`, which could be intercepted by the metaclass. Instead, it does `type(a).__dict__['descriptor']`. (Source: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors, and `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` in https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html confirms that this also applies to `__set__`).